# Performing ANOVA with missing data

Tags: anova, missing-data

I conducted a two-factor experiment with 3 replications on flower diameter under nutrient treatments. I got the data that look like this:

| Factor A | Factor B | Replication | Flower diameter (cm) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 1 | 2.2 |
| A1 | B1 | 2 | 2.3 |
| A1 | B1 | 3 | 2.2 |
| A1 | B2 | 1 | 2.1 |
| A1 | B2 | 2 | 1.9 |
| A1 | B2 | 3 | 1.8 |
| A2 | B1 | 1 | 1.6 |
| A2 | B1 | 2 | 1.3 |
| A2 | B1 | 3 | 1.3 |
| A2 | B2 | 1 | did not bloom |
| A2 | B2 | 2 | did not bloom |
| A2 | B2 | 3 | did not bloom |

As you can see, the entire A2B2 treatment did not produce flowers. So how do I perform ANOVA with this one? I don't suppose replacing missing data with 0 would be statistically correct.

Answer (score 5):

This is not the usual missing data problem. Usually "missing data" means you didn't measure it, or someone didn't answer a question, or the scale broke, or something like that.

Here, it looks like something about A2 combined with B2 was really bad for growing flowers. You will want to figure out what that is. I don't think you can do ANOVA on these data as is, without risking being seriously misleading.

Comment: How about considering the response variable as ordinal and putting “did not bloom” at the lowest level?  The only key assumption that makes is that “did not bloom” needs to penalize the nutrient’s effect you are estimating.

Comment: I like this idea @FrankHarrell .  You could then do ordinal logistic regression.